# foo.Name undefined (type interface {} has no field or method Name)

Tags: list, go, containers

I use the native golang package "container/list" to manage inotify event in a stack. When I access at stack's item, I have a fail with the type (I think).

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/exp/inotify" 
    "container/list"
    "log"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    stack := list.New()
    watcher, err := inotify.NewWatcher()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

   err = watcher.Watch(os.Args[1])
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }

   for {
       select {
           case ev := <-watcher.Event:
               stack.PushFront(ev)

               fmt.Printf("%#v\n", ev)
        }

        foo := stack.Front().Value

        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", foo)
        log.Println("Name: ", foo.Name)
    }
}
```

When I dump **ev** variable, the object type is **&inotify.Event**.
When I pop one item and I dump the variable, my object type is **&inotify.Event**.

With the error message I think it's a problem with type object accept by interface but I don't find how define type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do type-assertion for `foo` into `*inotify.Event`, the stack doesn't know what it is, it just holds `interface{}` objects.

What you need to do is something like:

```
elem := stack.Front().Value
if foo, ok := elem.(*inotify.Event); ok {
       fmt.Printf("%#v\n", foo)
       log.Println("Name: ", foo.Name)
}
```

The `ok` bit makes sure if it's **not** an event, your program won't crash. Of course you need to handle the case that it isn't.

More info on interface conversions and type assertions: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions

Comment: It works and with documentation I could resolve my futures problems.